# Altium help with Routing

Tags: altium, routing

I am working with a new computer at my company learning Altium. I have created the schematic and the PCB files inside my project and successfully imported everything from the schematic to the PCB. My problem now is that all of the Route buttons are grey and unusable. Even all of my Auto Route options are grey. What problem would be causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you check out a license on the "My Account" page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple licenses, make sure you're using the one with proper permissions.